# distinguish include_directories with and without the 'SYSTEM' option in cmake

Tags: cmake

I am using `get_property( … PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)` for debugging in a CMake project. Is there a way to tell which of the include directories have been done with and without the `SYSTEM` option?

In the following example I see no difference

```
include_directories("../B")
include_directories(SYSTEM "../A")

get_property( reqs TARGET main PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "main requires ${reqs}")
```

prints:

```
-- main requires /home/pseyfert/coding/system/C/../B;/home/pseyfert/coding/system/C/../A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is target property [INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html), which contains those of include directories, which has been marked as *SYSTEM*.

---

As the property's name suggests (and as noted in docs), *INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES* contains only *INTERFACE* directories, which are propagated to the targets linked with given one. It is unclear from CMake docs, how *PRIVATE* include directories should be distinguished.